# Can I achieve the same with list comprehension?

Tags: list-comprehension

I am a Python beginner.

I spent an hour to do the following task with list comprehensions. Although I could create a list I could use it was not what wanted to get.

Problem: 
I have a list of lists consisting of 2 (or possibly more) strings e.g.:

l=[["1","2"], ["3", "4"]]

I wanted to int each element of the nested lists using list comprehensions (if possible).

I could do it using for loops:

`list_int=[]
for e in l:
    u=[]
    for j in e:
        u.append(int(j))
        if len(u)==len(l[1]):
            t.append(u)`

Is that also possible using list comprehensions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l=[["1","2"], ["3", "4"]]
[[int(x) for x in elm] for elm in l]
```

Output :

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.7

```
>>> l = [["1","2"],["3","4"]]
>>> l = [[map(int,ls)] for ls in l]
>>> l
[[[1, 2]], [[3, 4]]]
>>>
```

In python 3.4

```
>>> l = [["1","2"],["3","4"]]
>>> l = [list(map(int,ls)) for ls in l]
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>>
```